# Restart deamon process for django under apache for each request

Tags: django, wsgi

I have many django installation which must run under one URL only. So I have a structure like

1. Django Installation 1
2. Django Installation 2
3. Django Installation N

under my root directory.

Now from the URL "www.mysite.com/installation1" I pick up subpart "installation1" and set the os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] to "installation.settings" and let the request be handled. Now for the request "www.mysite.com/installation2" I must do the same. However since django caches site object, AppCache etc internally I must restart wsgi process before each request so that internal cache of django gets cleared. ( I know performance would not be good but Im not worried about that). To implement the above scenerio I have implemented the below solution:

1. In httpd.conf as WSGIDaemonProcess django processes=5 threads=1
2. In the django.core.handlers.wsgi I made the following change in def "**call**"

   ```
   if environ['mod_wsgi.process_group'] != '':
       import signal, os
       print 'Sending the signal to kill the wsgi process'
       os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
   return response
   ```

My assumption being that deamon process would be killed at each request after the response has been sent. I want to confirm this assumption that my process would only be killed only and only after my response has been sent.

Also is there another way I can solve this problem

Thanks

EDIT: After the suggestion to set the MaxRequestsPerChild to 1 I made the following changes to  httpd.conf

KeepAlive Off
Listen 12021
MaxSpareThreads 1
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxRequestsPerChild 1
ServerLimit 1
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ThreadsPerChild 1
WSGIDaemonProcess django processes=5 threads=1

But my process is not getting restarted at each request. once the process is started it keeps on processing the request. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using the apache directive `MaxRequestsForChild` to **1** as stated in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild

However it will be global to every process daemon.

**Update:**

Or you chould check `maximum-requests` option into WSGIDaemonProcess as in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines

Comment: I read about this also. However this link http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=218 says that request must be finished in 5 seconds. Is there a way I can increase this limit somehow?

Comment: However on this http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg84691.html user have talked about setting it to 1. I will try to implement it and see the result.

Comment: Sorry it was falso alarm after couple of tests it appeared that deamon process is not starting for each request. Sorry for the hasty reply

Comment: On the surface maximum-requests seems to be working but this time I would like to run some rigorous tests. Will update you soon . Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. There's a reason why WSGI processes last longer than a single request - you say you're not worried about performance, but that's still no reason to do this. I don't know why you think you need to - plenty of people run multiple Django sites on one server, and none of them have ever felt the need to kill the process after each request.

Instead you need to ensure each site runs in its own WSGI process. See the mod_wsgi documentation for how to do this: [Application Groups](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Defining_Application_Groups) seems like a good place to start.

Comment: I have 1000's of such django websites and currently I cannot afford to have each django wesite its own WSGI process. Also I just want to add that these websites are accessed say 40 to 50 times in a day. This is one way I think how I can do that. If there is any other way to handle this issue please give me a pointer. The question still remains that would wsgi process would kill itself only after request has been sent?

Comment: Well now I'm even more confused. Why would you have "thousands" of websites on the same server that need separate global data? Sounds like you're doing something odd inside your code that is keeping global state where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Lets say I have this strange requirement and I cant change it. I need to run all these websites on one server and need to figure out a way. This is only way I can figure out. If there is any other way I would like know about.